Google Sheets Event to Open Insert Image function
I am creating a form for work that when my employees fill it out, they have the option to add photos to their report. I'm trying to make it slightly easier by combining so many cells into one and that when they click that group of cells, it will automatically open the insert image over cell function. I don't really know where to start.
Also,
I'd like to create a button they can click to "submit" the form and it load the "Email" prompt found under the File menu.
Are either of these possible or am I just blowing smoke in the wind?
Not sure where to begin. I have searched and searched but have not found any answers that meet my dilemma.

The question implies that the "form" is within the spreadsheet. Have you considered using a Google Form?

@Tedinoz yes I have, however, the amount of fields would make it a very large form and where I need fields side-by-side, it’s better for me to use sheets.
